# Reading serial port data at COM port

Tags: usb, labview, modbus, com-port

I'm trying to automate the reading of data from an elmeasure instrument (Voltmeter alpha+). This instrument has RS485 port. I have connected it to "RS-485 to USB converter" and the other end (USB end) is connected to my laptop (Windows 10). I want to read the instrument reading using NI labVIEW. But how do I interface it?

I tried tools like modbus, wireshark, putty, directly through command prompt, and serial read via labVIEW.
nothing worked. Only in MODSCAN I'm able to read. How do I interface this with LabVIEW?

Answer (score 1):

LabVIEW should be able to connect to any Modbus device.

If you follow [this tutorial](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000x0QgCAI&l=en-EN) you should be able to make it work.

If you are looking for a straightforward solution, something similar to Modscan but within LabVIEW you might want to try [this library](https://www.ni.com/es-es/support/downloads/tools-network/download.modbus-master.html#374378) and [manual](https://lavag.org/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=14276).

For completeness, the other tools you mention are probably not very useful for your purposes:

- Wireshark can be used to monitor Modbus traffic between other devices but you won't be able to use it as a master or slave.
- PuTTY is just a terminal, you would be able to use it to send queries to your meter and read its answers but you would have to do it manually and that would be very inconvenient, to say the least.

If you are looking for alternatives to LabVIEW you can try [QModMaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/#:%7E:text=QModMaster%20is%20a%20free%20Qt,all%20traffic%20on%20the%20bus.) if you want a solution with a GUI. If what you need is a library you can try [libmodbus](https://libmodbus.org/) or [pymodbus](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus).

Obviously, that's just a small sample of tools, there are many more.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try the tools and update you on the same